# Convert to Lambda expression using java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am newly learning lambda expression. I am trying to calculate values.

**Here is example:**

```
double sendersCount = 0.0;
double reciversCount = 0.0;
for(RecordDTO record : records){
   if("1".equals(record.getSendersId())) {
     sendersCount += record.getCount().doubleValue();
   } else {
     reciversCount +=  record.getCount().doubleValue();
   }
}

class Record{

private String id;
private BigDecimal count;
private String senderId;

//setters
//getters
}
```

How we can achieve using Streams and maps?

Comment: `sendersCount` isn't `int`. It's a `double`.

Comment: records is list

Comment: IMHO your current approach would be better than any stream approach. you're better off sticking with the current approach.

Comment: `Record` is a bad name for a class. It's used in Java 14 by `java.lang.Record`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one way, you can possibly partition the list and then `sum` the appropriate attribute as -

```
Map<Boolean, List<Record>> partitioned = records.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(rec -> rec.getSendersId().equals("1")));

double sendersCount = partitioned.get(Boolean.TRUE).stream()
        .mapToDouble(Record::getSendersCount).sum();
double receiversCount = partitioned.get(Boolean.FALSE).stream()
        .mapToDouble(Record::getReceiversCount).sum();
```

or as Ousmane has pointed out, you can use downstream `summingDouble` with a condition to map such as:

```
Map<Boolean, Double> summingValue = records.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(r -> "1".equals(r.getSendersId()),
                Collectors.summingDouble(r -> "1".equals(r.getSendersId()) ?
                        r.getSendersCount() : r.getReceiversCount())));
```